# Increment values in vector conditionally (conditional restarting running sum)-- vectorized version?

Tags: r, vectorization

Given a vector of binary values `out_2` the code below returns a vector 
of same length as `out_2` called `out_1`.
The entries of `out_1` counts the number of successive similar items left in `out_2` before the next sign switch.  If you print the final `cbind()` I think you will see what I mean.

```
  library(zoo)
  n = 10
  out_2 = rep(NA, n)
  out_2[sample.int(n, 3)] = sample(c(-1, 1), 3, replace = TRUE)
  out_2 = zoo::na.locf(out_2)
  out_1 = out_2
  out_1[length(out_2)] = 1
  for(i in (length(out_2) - 1):1){
    out_1[i] = ifelse(out_2[i + 1] == out_2[i], out_1[i + 1] + 1, 1)  
  }
cbind(out_1, out_2)
```

I was wondering if there is a one liner vectorized way to get `out_1` from `out_2` (i.e. vectoring the explicit for loop)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `rle` from base `R`. The tricky part is to get the reverse order for the `out_1` vector, so it has (?) to go through `lapply'

```
out_1<- unlist(lapply(rle(out_2)$lengths, function(x) seq(x, by=-1)))
```

And the result is:

```
cbind(out_1, out_2)
      out_1 out_2
 [1,]     2    -1
 [2,]     1    -1
 [3,]     1     1
 [4,]     6    -1
 [5,]     5    -1
 [6,]     4    -1
 [7,]     3    -1
 [8,]     2    -1
 [9,]     1    -1
```

If you're flexible with the output and you don't need it to be in reverse order, you can simply use the `sequence` function.

```
out_1<- sequence(rle(out_2)$lengths)
cbind(out_1, out_2)
      out_1 out_2
 [1,]     1    -1
 [2,]     2    -1
 [3,]     1     1
 [4,]     1    -1
 [5,]     2    -1
 [6,]     3    -1
 [7,]     4    -1
 [8,]     5    -1
 [9,]     6    -1
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution iterates over grouped consecutive values (not over `out_2` as in your example). Basically, we group consecutive values, check how large this group is and create vector `N:1`.

```
foo <- rle(out_2)
cbind(unlist(sapply(foo$lengths, function(x) x:1)), 
      rep(foo$values, foo$lengths))
```